# How to log docker build installation package errors

Tags: logging, docker, docker-build

When I build a docker image via dockerfile using: `docker build -t test/app1 .`

The docker builds successfully however, I noticed there are some errors as it installing packages through the build. How can I track/log these package installation errors on linux?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean under `log`? As I understood if you noticed this errors it was logged

Comment: while it is building it outputs a lot of things installing. Ive noticed that with all the errors, it would take a while to manually view the errors. could i put the output of the build command for logging? I just want to see where ever there is an error

Comment: if your errors has some pattern which you can write as regexp then use something like this `docker build -t test/app1 | grep <regexp> >> log.txt`

Comment: I tried this and I am getting an error assuming the syntax is `docker build -t test/app1 .`   would the proper syntax be `docker build -t test/app1 . | grep <regexp> >> log.txt`?  where is the log.txt going to be stored?

Comment: if your error contains `ERROR` just replace `<regexp>` by `ERROR`, log.txt stores in the same dir where you call your build

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `docker build -t test/app1 . 2> ~/log.txt`

This command will create a log.txt file in the home directory of your user containing standard error output of `docker build ...` command.

Comment: Tried this command, however does not record the errors mentioned as the build is installing packages where the errors reside from

Answer (score 0):

below command is record all logs :

> docker build -t test/app1 . > ~/log.txt 2>&1